# MediaCaptureViewController iOS Adobe Air native extension

Tags: ios, air, air-native-extension

Is there a way of writing a native extension for iOS using the MediaCaptureViewController to play video from local device storage on the iPhone/iPad (prerecorded or after it has been recorded) on StageVideo within the Air-App. The native Air SDK only contains browseForImage() but not browseForVideo() so does that mean its technically not possible or that it just hasn't been implemented yet? Are there any existing native extensions to solve this issue?